# how to make sense of pattern matching of optionals in for loop in swift

Tags: swift, pattern-matching, option-type

in a practice problem I was asked to print out all elements that are not nil in an array of string, and I realize

```
for case let name? in names{
    print(name)
}
```

would do the job. But isn't it counter-intuitive?

In the snippet, I read it as "for every element (with actual value or nil)that is  in names", but in fact it should be "for every element (actual value)that is in names".

Can anyone help me to make sense of the snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know why this code:

```
let names = ["b", nil, "x"]
for case let name? in names {
    print(name)
}
```

Produces this output:

```
b
x
```

You are wondering what happens to the `nil`.

The answer is the ["Optional Pattern" found in the *Language Reference*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html):

> The optional pattern provides a convenient way to iterate over an
>   array of optional values in a for-in statement, executing the body of
>   the loop only for non-nil elements.

The `case` keyword is vital. It changes the nature of the `for` loop significantly. As you can see from this complier error, `name?` inside the loop is not an optional at all.

[image: compiler error using guard on non-optional]

Think of the `?` as an operator that removes the optionality of `name`. If the assignment would result in `nil`, that iteration of the loop does not happen, and the next iteration starts.

Notice that without the `case` you do not get the same behavior at all.

This:

```
for name in names {
    print(name)
}
```

Will get this output:

```
Optional("b")
nil
Optional("x")
```

And that neither of these work at all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: so really, the ? here isn't marking it optional, instead it is a pattern matching and we just have to memorize it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter with conditional and then print the result like this:

```
let nameNotNil = names.filter{$0 != nil} //filter all values diferent nil
print(nameNotNil) // can be nil if any didnt has strings
```

Comment: can you interpret the code snippet I have above? I think I might either understand optional wrong or pattern matching wrong.